# How to create a smaller dataframe from an existing dataframe with the same numbers per label

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 50k rows and two columns, `item` and `labels`. I want to reduce the number of rows but keep the same values for all labels.
So it looks like:

- Label "notebook": 1000 rows
- Label "ballpoint": 1000 rows
- Label "pencil": 1000 rows
- Label "eraser": 1000 rows
- Label "pencil sharpener": 1000 rows

So from 50k rows, it reduces to only 5000 rows with the same number of rows for each label.

Comment: `.groupby('label').head(1000)`? Is that what you're looking for? If not, make a [mre]. For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). Like, for the sake of example, you could probably do with as little as two labels with 5 rows each down to 2 rows each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform stratified sampling which simply means converting your data into groups and then sample from each group.

The sampling could be proportionate or disproportionate. Since you have already mentioned that you want 1000 rows for each label, go for disproportionate sampling. The sample code is below:

```
data = {    
    "item": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    "label": ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B'],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Sampling two rows for each labels
df.groupby("label").sample(n=2)
print(df)
```

```
   item label
0   3   A
1   7   A
2   6   B
3   5   B
4   4   C
5   8   C
```

Comment: I think you can just use [`.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html) instead of `.apply(.sample)`.

Comment: No ,It will give error. Here sample() is extracting 2 row from each group i.e. x

Comment: What's the error? It worked fine for me.

Comment: My bad, I wrote .apply(sample). Yes it working fine, more elegant :)